# TCL Regular expression to trim the string from specific special character

Tags: regex, tcl

My TCL Regexp is as below

```
regexp {((\d:[\da-zA-Z]+))} "3001:470:8865:2E01::190:201" out
```

current value of out is the complete string

```
3001:470:8865:2E01::190:201
```

I want the string before ::

```
3001:470:8865:2E01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match single-colon separated alphanumeric char chunks at the start of a string:

```
regexp {^\w+(?::\w+)*} "3001:470:8865:2E01::190:201" out
puts $out
```

Output: `3001:470:8865:2E01`

See the [Tcl demo online](https://ideone.com/T96I3A) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WQFM6Q/1). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `\w+` - one or more letters, digits or underscores
- `(?::\w+)*` - zero or more occurrences of a colon and then one or more letters, digits or underscores.

You might also consider precising `\w` pattern to `[\dA-Za-z]` in case you want to match letters and digits only, and replace the first `\w+` with `\d+`:

```
regexp {\d+(?::[\dA-Za-z]+)*} "3001:470:8865:2E01::190:201" out
```

See [this Tcl demo](https://ideone.com/w5DhxW) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WQFM6Q/2).

Comment: This is the more precise match ++

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, remove the stuff you don't want:

```
regsub {::.*} "3001:470:8865:2E01::190:201" {} out

puts $out  ;# ==> 3001:470:8865:2E01
```

Answer (score 0):

This will catch everything before `::` : `(.*)::`

See: https://regex101.com/r/LzqnmZ/1

Comment: That works for this simple regex, but note that Tcl regexes are not PCRE: http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm

Answer (score 0):

To stop the RE at `::`, use a forward lookahead:

```
regexp {.*(?=::)} "3001:470:8865:2E01::190:201" out
```

The `out` variable is not written to if the RE does not match.